# PSRule's in-flight assessment output

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the following pipeline that was to get the current (in-flight) resources from a Resource Group, and run PSRule on these existing resources.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:          
- stage: Assess
  displayName: In-flight assessment
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
      - checkout: self

      - task: ps-rule-install@02
        displayName: Install PSRule.Rules.Azure
        inputs:
          module: 'PSRule.Rules.Azure'

      - task: AzurePowerShell@5
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: serviceConnection
          ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
          Inline: |
            Get-AzContext;
            Export-AzRuleData -ResourceGroupName 'myrgname' -OutputPath  'out/templates/';   
            Invoke-PSRule -Module 'PSRule.Rules.Azure' -InputPath 'out/templates/*.json' -OutputPath '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)';
          azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

The pipeline runs fine and without any error, however there doesn't seem to be any assessment done over the JSON file.  What am I missing here, as I have followed the one or two examples that exist.

Screenshot from the result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In command `Invoke-PSRule`, you have set `outputpath` but not with `outputformat`, it won't output the result in devops log. In addition, fix the input path value. Sample below:

```
      - task: ps-rule-install@02
        displayName: Install PSRule.Rules.Azure
        inputs:
          module: 'PSRule.Rules.Azure'

      - task: AzurePowerShell@5
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'ARMConn1'
          ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
          Inline: |
            Get-AzContext;
            Export-AzRuleData -ResourceGroupName 'wadeTestRG1' -OutputPath  'out/templates/'; 
            cd out/templates
            Invoke-PSRule -Module 'PSRule.Rules.Azure' -InputPath './*.json' -OutputPath test -OutputFormat json;
          azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s'
          artifact: 'tes'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Check the artifact content, it will show the **test** result(the output result)

[image]

If you would like to check the result in devops log, use `Invoke-PSRule -Module 'PSRule.Rules.Azure' -InputPath ./*.json -As Summary;` in yaml instead.

[image]